# Find SelectedText by mouse Selection in div jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find it out `selected text` on div which select by mouse. I found out [.select()](http://api.jquery.com/select/) method for select. but its not accomplish my problem.

i want to something like :

```
 <div id='mydiv'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</div>
```

when i selected `simply` text using mouse selection.i found it out using `jquery`.
or something else another selected i want to get it.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to select it.
all you need to do is to add a click handler.

```
document.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);
function handleTouchEnd(e){
   console.log(e.target.innerHTML);// returns whatever is there in the div
   console.log(e.target.textContent);// better option, as it returns text only
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know what I want. How do I get the selected text? So if the user highlights "simply" in the innerHTML or textContent how do I get only the highlighted part?