# Count number of characters in selected text

Tags: jquery

`asdf`

Given this div, if a user were to select the word `asdf` with their cursor, the the character count would be **4**.

In JavaScript, how can you determine what the user has selected with their cursor; more specifically, text.

jQuery library preferred.

I've tried:

```
var text = document.getSelection().toString();
var length = document.getSelection().toString().length;
if (text) {
    alert(text);
}
if (length) {
    alert(length);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxjgW/

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924851/find-selectedtext-by-mouse-selection-in-div-jquery

Comment: @Edward, that doesn't help.

Comment: @OP I just copied your code, pasted it on the console in Chrome's Developer tools, ran it, and it alerted what I had selected...

Comment: @darkajax, http://jsfiddle.net/fxjgW/ It doesn't alert `asdf` when I select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your updated question I see the problem is that you're not triggering the text selection, as far as I know there is no DOM event for text selection, **but** you can set it for `mouseup`, like this:

```
$(document.body).on('mouseup', function(){
    var text = document.getSelection().toString();
    var length = document.getSelection().toString().length;
    if (text) {
        alert(text);
    }
    if (length) {
        alert(length);
    }
});
```

[**Update jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/cx37Q/)

Comment: I gave that a try, but it didn't seem to work. I've updated my post with what I've tried.

Comment: This works great except for the case where the user drags their mouse outside the bounds of the jsfiddle iframe and the mouseup is never caught. Not sure if the OP has some similar situation.